# Prefill form using AngularFire2 Object Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I'm unable to pre-fill a form with the data stored at a location in firebase using AngularFire2. The template has multiple inputs like:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(propertyForm.value)" #propertyForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <md-input-container>
      <input md-input placeholder="Postcode" type="text" id="postcode" required [(ngModel)]="model.postcode" name="postcode">
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

This then connects to the component which has a model (Property) which the constructor links directly to the object I want to display in the form.

```
export class PropertyFormComponent implements OnInit {

model: FirebaseObjectObservable<Property>;
  submitted = false;
  propertyForm;

  constructor(private propertyService: PropertyService, af: AngularFire) {
    this.model = af.database.object('/properties/MGQ34xmYDdT8IGLaj3zvBwZjWgW2');
  }
}
```

I know that the object path is correct as I can submit the form and update the object but the ngModel binding isn't joining to the Firebase object and I can't figure out why. I've tried replacing the Firebase object with a handcrafted object and it worked fine. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Object is an `Observable`, not a plain JS object, which means you can't apply `ngModel` as is. You could actually try and convert the `Observable` to a plain object, that way `ngModel` can be used.

So first get the Observable and then subscribe it:

```
constructor(private propertyService: PropertyService, af: AngularFire) {
  this.model = af.database.object('/properties/MGQ34xmYDdT8IGLaj3zvBwZjWgW2');
  this.model.subscribe(d => {this.model = d}); // add this line!
}
```

You now have a plain object to work with :)

A better option would be, if you can subscribe to the object directly, but not having to use Firebase, I'm not sure if this works, but you could try:

```
af.database.object('/properties/MGQ34xmYDdT8IGLaj3zvBwZjWgW2')
  .subscribe(d => { 
     this.model = d
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that seems to have done the trick although the form still isn't being filled as the object is undefined. I think this might be a timing issue as console log shows this.model being correct but comes after all the errors

Comment: You are welcome! And as to the undefined error: This is async, so view is rendered before data has been retrieved, you can solve it by using `*ngIf*` so you could use `<form *ngIf="model">` That should do the trick :)

Comment: great, that should give me enough to work it out from here. Thanks!